# Copying the entire row if the cell isn't one of four determined values

Tags: vba, excel

*Edited*
  this is the code that answers the question

```
Dim i As Integer   

For i = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count        
    If Cells(i, "C") <> "Q" Then            
    Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)       
    End If
Next
```

*edit2*
  I'm now facing minor problems it would be great to figure out what's wrong with them.
  1- This code is copying the cells but the problem is after pasting them in the other sheet there is gaps all over the place (they are the places of non-copied cells)

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If Cells(i, "P") <> "Q"  Then

    Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)

    End If
Next
```

**the fix for this problem is to add**
   `.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`
  **after the line that does the copy and pasting. I tried that before but i used Offset(1) and that didn't work**

2-This code causes Excel to hang and i have to force it to close but when i reopen it the copied cells are there in the new sheet(i kind of know the problem, i think it's because Excel will check all cells since they are = 0 but i tried using the same for loop as the previous code but i kept getting errors)

```
Dim ro As Long
For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").range("U:U")
If (Len(cell.Value) = 0) Then
            ro = (ro + 1)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(ro)
End If

Next
```

**the fix for #2 is to add a for loop of the rows count and include it, i knew that would fix it but i had problems with the syntax. The code needed the change in this line:**

```
For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").range("U" & i)
```

"i" being the for loop, just like the one in code #1

Comment: Post the code that you have tried so far and we can help you out. It's frowned upon to just ask for code to be made for you on SO. If you don't want to try I at all I suggest you hire someone for that job. But I'll write up some code to help you out.

Comment: +1 as you had posted in your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will iterate all of your rows in Column A and check if the text is a Q, W or E. If it isn't it'll copy that row.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    'Loop to move through the rows
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'Checks if it contains Q, W or E
        If Cells(i, 1) <> "Q" And Cells(i, 1) <> "W" And Cells(i, 1) <> "E" Then
            'Copy that row
            Rows(i).Copy
            'You said you know how to do the copy part so I won't include the rest...
        Else
            'Do something else
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Next time actually attempt the problem before asking for help. If it weren't so simple, people probably wouldn't help out too much. This is also something which is a quick google or SO search away.

Comment: @pnuts Now I understand, I updated my wording, should be understandable now. I was confused on what you were saying.

Comment: sorry for not posting the code earlier, i posted this question and kept trying but came back to find you code which worked fine thanks for that. Except that after pasting in the new sheet, there are spaces between the rows (places of rows that were not copied) i tried using End(xlUp) and Offset but it screws up the whole thing. i added the code im using in the main post so any ideas on how to fix this would be great

Answer (score 0):

`AutoFilter` does this quickly by avoiding loops, and will avoid the gaps on the rows copy

If you do have lower case `q` or `w` data then an advanced filter using `EXACT` will be needed on the output in the second sheet. See [Debra's example here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/339110-case-sensitive-advanced-filtering.html)

```
Sub Clean()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.[a1], ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
With rng1
   .AutoFilter Field:=1, Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Q", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>W"
   If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy ws2.[a1]
End With
ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But what i'm trying to do is copy the row if the cell doesn't match the criteria and not the other way around.  
  I tried using your code to see how it works but i kept getting errors, after the last change to the code i kept getting 1004 error or no cells found(it's the same code you posted i only changed this line)  
  `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(Op1, Op2, Op3, Op4, Op5, "=")`      

      Again, i'm not trying to copy the cell that matches the criteria but the cell that doesn't match it. Thanks

Comment: That fixed the errors, but i'm not getting the right output.  
  I will keep looking into it but is there any way to avoid the gaps while using the code in the main post because it's simpler to work with. Thanks

Comment: `but i'm not getting the right output` - whats happening?